# Return value of c# exe with exec

Tags: security, licensing, exec, inno-setup, pascal

i have a problem using inno setup. I'm installing an update with inno, and with the update.exe the user get a txtfile with a licencenumber. On his Unit this licencenumber readable by a dll function.

Before the installingprocess i have to compare these numbers. Only if this numbers are identical the user is trying to installing the update on the right machine with the right licence.

If i would put this check into an seperate exe, it would be easy to crack it by change the exe with one just doing nothing (no errorcode). So i want to split the checking into the seperated exe (where i check some other things like installed version number etc.) and the update.exe

In update exe, i want to read the txtfile inside the updatepackage - this is easy.
In check.exe i want to call the internal dll and get the licencenumber of the machine. I have to return this number as an int. C# allows me to do that.

But how can i get this number in innosetup?

I tried to take the errorcode for this (0=error - not right version etc, XXXXXXXXX = licencenumber of machine). But the errorcode is just 2 chars in inno. I get only 2 chars...

Saving the number in another file would'nt be a solution cause the user can crack it this way... Is it possible to get the number into inno without giving the user the chance to manilpulate??

Answer (score 0):

If you move the code into a DLL (either COM or a plain stdcall DLL) then it can be used by Inno and pass extra data between them including full strings, etc.